# How to define caveman2 routes in multiple files/packages?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, caveman2

I want to have routes defined over multiple files, not just web.lisp. What is the correct way of doing this?

I tried writing another file with this code and it works:

```lisp
(in-package :mywebapp.web)

;; for @route annotation
(syntax:use-syntax :annot)


(defroute "/hello" ()
  (format nil "Hello World!"))
```

However, what I thought was the correct approach was to have another package definition and then either import `:mywebapp.web` into my new package, or import my new package `:mywebapp.controllers.hello` into `:mywebapp.web`.

Can you please explain to me the correct approach?

When I created my own package and imported `:mywebapp.web` I got the following error:

`There is no applicable method for the generic function #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION (COMMON-LISP:SETF NINGLE/APP:ROUTE) (1)> when called with arguments (#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (#:PARAMS1141) :IN "/project/src/controllers/hello.lisp") {53CE5F6B}> NIL "/hello"). See also: The ANSI Standard, Section 7.6.6`

However I had imported into the new packages all the same imports as in the `.web` package...

Note that I redacted the path...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in package CL-USER (in the REPL) I wrote the following form and asked Emacs/Slime for its macroexpansion:

```
(caveman2:defroute "/hello" ())
```

The result is:

```
(SETF (APPLY #'NINGLE/APP:ROUTE
             (CONS
              (CAVEMAN2.APP:FIND-PACKAGE-APP #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">)
              (LIST "/hello")))
        (LAMBDA (#:PARAMS1721) (DECLARE (IGNORABLE #:PARAMS1721))))
```

This corresponds to your error, because ultimately when combining `apply` with the `(cons ...)` forms, the code will be calling `route` with the result of `find-package-app` and `"/hello"`.

But in your case, the result of `find-package-app` is NIL, meaning no such app was found. I probably would have expected a better error message here, but anyway the solution is to explicitly specify the application:

```
(caveman2:defroute (other-package:*app* "/hello") ())
```

This macroexpands as:

```
(SETF (APPLY #'NINGLE/APP:ROUTE (LIST OTHER-PACKAGE:*APP* "/hello"))
        (LAMBDA (#:PARAMS1723) (DECLARE (IGNORABLE #:PARAMS1723))))
```

There is however little documentation about that, I had to look at the source code.

Basically when an application is instantiated, the current value of `*package*` is captured and associated in a hash-table to the application instance.

Comment: Thanks! Would love to learn how did you figure out that passing the `other-package:*app*` would solve the issue. Did you download the code in github and checked the macro definition of defroute?

Comment: @Daniel More or less, I installed it with `(ql:quickload :caveman2)` and used Emacs/Slime to navigate the source code

Comment: Wow, I thought I could figure this out from what you wrote but now I can't find the `*app*` definition, I thought it was in the `app.lisp` file, but I kept trying and it didn't work. I even tried this in the REPL to no avail `(caveman2.app:find-package-app (asdf:system-relative-pathname :project-name #P"app.lisp"))` Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, this was unclear, this `other-package:*app*` does not exist, it is an example of how you would need to go to refer to a variable named `*app*` that would be defined in some other package and bound to an Caveman application. For example, if you follow the skeleton defined by `make-project`, the src/web.lisp file defines a class named <web> that intherits from <app>, and defines a global `*web*` variable that is an instance of that class. So that would be this variable that should be referred from other files/packages